# Алгоритм получения всех дочерних элементов для текущего элемента дерева

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Имеется коллекция типа `List<TreeItem>`, сконфигурированная таким образом, что представляет из себя иерархическую структуру объектов. Каждый объект коллекции знает о своём родителе (`TreeItem Parent`), и о своих "ближайших" предках, находящихся на уровень ниже по иерархии (`List<TreeItem> Children`).
Код `TreeItem`:

```
public class TreeItem
{
    public bool HasParent { get; set; }
    public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
    public TreeItem Parent { get; set; }
    public List<TreeItem> Children { get; set; }        
}
```

Необходимо реализовать статический метод, который будет принимать в качестве аргумента элемент `TreeItem` из коллекции и изменит коллекцию `List<TreeItem> Children` этого элемента так, чтобы она содержала не только своих "ближайших" предков (которые находятся на одну ступень ниже по иерархии), но и всех последующих до самого последнего элемента. Ломаю уже очень долго голову над этим. Пытался подсунуть к решению проблемы рекурсию - но ничего не выходит. Запутался. Помогите!

**UPDATE**

Пробовал таким образом:

```
public static void GetNestedChildren(TreeItem hierarchicalItem)
{
    var newChildrenCollection = new List<TreeItem> { hierarchicalItem };
    if (!hierarchicalItem.HasChildren) return;
    foreach (var child in hierarchicalItem.Children)
    {
        newChildrenCollection.Add(child);
        GetNestedChildren(child);
    }
    hierarchicalItem.Children.AddRange(newChildrenCollection);
}
```

Comment: добавляйте код, как именно пробовали

Comment: на каждой итерации создается новый `newChildrenCollection` передавайте его или возвращайте

Comment: Эээ... Поиск в глубину или в ширину, выбирайте, что вам удобнее.

Comment: @VladD, не совсем понял, о чём Вы.

Comment: @klutch1991: Ну, при помощи обхода в глубину получаете список всех дочерних элементов, заменяете исходный список на полученный.

Comment: @VladD, Навскидку загуглил, и нашёл алгоритмы обхода в глубину для бинарных деревьев. А моё дерево таки не бинарное.

Comment: @klutch1991: Так вроде ж ничем не отличается по сути. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: @VladD, тут уже поиск в глубину идет, просто результат не сохраняется

Comment: @Grundy: Ну это да. Но поиск хоть возвращает найденный список, я надеялся, что это подскажет ТС'у что-нибудь. [Функция названа неудачно — как может `Get...` возвращать `void`?]

Comment: хм... а вы уверены что хотите именно того, о чем написали? расход памяти получается совершенно безумный, если взять всего 3 уровня дерева по k дочерних элементов в узлах, получите одних ссылок k^3. Причем информация будет продублирована по несколько раз, это точно то, что вам нужно получить?

Comment: @rdorn, да, т.к. общее количество элементов во всём дереве вряд ли превысит сотню.